# Nyromodal fixed position window

Tags: jquery, position, fixed, nyromodal

I'm using nyromodal, and having trouble giving the pop-up window a fixed position relative to the background. I.e. I have positioned it where I want it to go, but when the browser window is resized the pop-up shifts in relation to the background page content. I understand this is a feature of nyromodal, but I'd quite like to turn it off. I can't find a function in the docs to do that. Does anyone have any ideas?

CSS snippet:

```
.nyroModalCont {
    position: absolute;
    margin:20px 25px 25px 25px;
    background:#000;
}
```

Trigger:

```
echo '<a href="showimage.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="trigger" rel="gal">';
echo '<img src="'.$this->ImageDir.$row['id'].'/thumb/'.$row['thumb'].'" border="0" />';
echo '</a>';
```

Thanks,
HR

Comment: Do you need to have no resizing? Could you describe better the behaviour that you need? What type of modal window do you have: an iframe or just a div one?

Comment: I've put a bit of code in the original question above. Basically I want the pop-up to always appear say 20px below a certain point. It does this fine. But when I resize the browser window Nyromodal shifts the pop-up window -- this means the top edge of the pop-up changes position in relation to the page behind it. I want it to stay in the same place in relation to the page behind it. Hope that makes sense! HR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid shifting (and resizing) of a pop-up after you resize the browser window, you can overwrite the `resize` function (with no code inside) into the nyroModal options:

```
$('.trigger').nyroModal({
  resize: function(recalc) {},
});
```

As alternative (or adding), according to your needs, you can change *css properties* using nyroModal callbacks that deal with resizing:

```
$('.trigger').nyroModal({
  callbacks: {
    beforeResize: function(nm) {
    },
    afterResize: function(nm) {
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks Macgyver, that works perfectly & does exactly what I asked. Unfortunately I now realise I asked the wrong thing! Now when a window is resized, the pop-up window doesn't move at all, which is what I asked. What I should have emphasised was that I want it to stay in the same position in relation to what's under it -- so when e.g. you resize the browser and move the right-edge (so that the site shifts about as you move it) I want the pop-up to move exactly in accordance. It may not be possible. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. NyroModal performs own work without keep into account what is under the modal window, so  I guess you have to rewrite the resize function to achieve this behaviour and this isn't a simple task.

Comment: How about if I wanted the window always to be, say, 20px from the top of the browser? Apologies if it's bad form to ask another question in a comment, I can repost as a separate question if necessary.

Comment: What you need it's possible, but without rewrite the resize function is no possible to have a good animation. I mean you can put inside both beforeShowCont callback and afterResize callback the code  $('.nyroModalCont').css('top', '20px') to fix the position of the pop-up window but after each resizing the pop-up window will shift up or down before to stop at 20px from the top.